# Intellij IDEA Unix line endings for new files

Tags: intellij-idea, line-endings

How do you configure Intellij IDEA so that it will use Unix line endings for all source files it creates in the future? The Google search results all refer to the way to convert an existing file to Unix line endings, but I want to solve the problem once and for all, so I don't need to keep going back and paying attention to it.

Comment: Have you tried to set it in "Settings | Editor | Code Style - Line separator"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line endings could be configured in "Settings | Editor | Code Style - Line separator"